# Howto Dynamic map properties of T in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework I can in MyContext override the OnModelCreating methode and do stuff like:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      //...
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(x => x.Foo.Value)
            .HasColumnName("Foo");
      modelBuilder.Entity<OtherEntity>()
            .Property(x => x.Bar.Value)
            .HasColumnName("Bar");
  }
```

Where Foo and Bar are properties of ISomeInterface defining a property Value.

However, I don't want to specify this mapping for every EntityType in MyContext. I would like to define the pattern in a more generic way (propebly using reflextion). Somthing like

```
var types = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach(var type in types){
    var props = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType is ISomeInterface);
    foreach (var prop in props){
         var valueProp = prop.PropertyType.GetProperty("Value");
         modelbuilder.GetEntity(type)
            .Property(valueProp)
            .HasColumnName(prop.Name)
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: There are many ways - custom conventions, using `DbModelBuilder` class `Properties` and `Types` methods etc. But the example makes no sense since it's just duplicating the EF default column name convention.

Comment: No, the default would map the properties _Foo_ and _Bar_ to their own table and store the value in a column named "Value". I want the _Value_ to be stored in the table of _MyEntity_ and _OtherEntity_ in a column respectively named "Foo" and "Bar".